# markers not being displayed on google maps from XML file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-maps

So I'm trying to create markers on to a google map with queried lat/long from a database and saved onto a XML file. I'm trying to grab the locations from the XML file and into a new google marker, but am unable to display any markers on the map.

My HTML/JavaScript

```
//Test for markers
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 1200px;
        height: 900px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>   
    <script>
    var map;
      function initialize() { 
       var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.0400, -122.7400);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 10,
          center: myLatlng
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
      }
      loadMarkers();
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function loadMarkers(){
        map.markers = map.markers || []
        downloadUrl("schools.xml", function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("school");
            for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
                var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("long")));
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map:map,
                    position: point,
                    title:name
                });
                map.markers.push(marker);             
            }
        });
      }

    function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
             new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
             new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload = "initialize()">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
-<Schools>   
<school loc="POINT (-122.549936 37.955014)" lat="37.955014" long="-122.549936" county="Marin" zip="94904" state="CA" city="Kentfield" name2="" name="College of Marin"/>  
<school loc="POINT (-122.564302 37.969594)" lat="37.969594" long="-122.564302" county="Marin" zip="94960" state="CA" city="San Anselmo" name2="" name="San Francisco Theological Seminary"/>    
<school loc="POINT (-122.514654 37.980014)" lat="37.980014" long="-122.514654" county="Marin" zip="94901" state="CA" city="San Rafael" name2="" name="Dominican University of California"/>
</Schools>
```

Comment: Could be a timing issue. I would move the  loadMarkers call into the initialize function to begin with. What does the error console say?

Comment: @lucas I corrected the loadMarkers into the initialize function, but still no luck. The error console tells me that doNothing is undefined

Comment: That is because `doNothing` is not defined...  This is a good definition of `doNothing`: `function doNothing() {}`

Comment: @geocodezip I'm following google's guide and it also has it as undefined, what should it be defined as?

Comment: I added it to my previous comment.  Does the example you are following work?  Which google's guide?

Comment: @geocodezip here is the link: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Comment: It is defined there in the code in ["Putting it all together"](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#putting-it-all-together).

Comment: Does your XML really have that "-" at the beginning of the first line?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'markers' of undefined` on this line:

```
    map.markers = map.markers || []
```

You are calling the `loadMarkers` before the map is defined.  Call it inside the initialize routine.

```
function initialize() { 
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.0400, -122.7400);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  loadMarkers();
}
```